# Find specific keyword on column 1 and append new line on column 2 shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have one text file look like the followings:

```
 empty      2
 23         8
 19         1
 empty
 11
```

I am trying to append new line on column 2 if column 1 has keyword "empty". Any one know how to do this? The following is the expected output:

```
 empty      
 23         2
 19         8
 empty
 11         1
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What you are asking for doesn't match your 'Before' and 'After' pictures:. Adding a newline to column 2 would put "'2' on a separate line, it would not cause it to push '8' and '1' down.  Your 'After' picture suggests that you really want to treat the file as columns, not lines.

Comment: Yeah, you are right Greg. I want to keep this file as columns as well. Just like described on the output file. Any idea to do this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script for gnu awk:

```
{ col1[ FNR ] = $1
  col2[ FNR ] = sprintf("%s %s",$2, $3)
}

END {
  k2 = 0;
  for( k1 = 1; k1 <= FNR; k1++) {
      if( col1[ k1 ] != "empty" ){
         k2++
         print col1[ k1], col2[ k2]
      }
      else print col1[ k1]
  }
}
```

It stores the values of column1 and (column 2 + column 3) in two different arrays. During the output ( in the `END`) it consumes a value from the second array only if the first column is not "empty".

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'p{t=$2;$2=p;p=t} $1=="empty"{if($2!=""){p=$2;$2=""}}1' file

empty                                                                                                                        
23 2
19 8
empty 
11 1
```

Comment: Yes, It works for 3 "empty" word on column 1! 
But, how if we have more "empty" word on column 1? Because it will skip some value on column 2. 
Thanks a lot! I really apriciate it

Comment: please post a test input, I'm not sure I understood what you meant.

Comment: The test input actually consists of 3 column. And I want to process it just like I mentioned before.
I pasted it through the following link: http://pasted.co/ca5a2da9
Thanks!